# Find Element by Attributes

Tags: delphi, browser, mshtml

How can I find an element by its tag and by specific attributes? This code I've written does find it by its tag, however it can't seem to find it by its attributes.

Why is there such behaviour with this code?

```
function FindElement(const Tag:String; const Attributes:TStringList):IHTMLElement;
var
  FAttributeName, FAttributeValue:String;
  Collection: IHTMLElementCollection;
  E:IHTMLElement;
  Count:Integer;
  i, j:Integer;
begin
  Collection := (EmbeddedWB1.Document as IHTMLDocument3).getElementsByTagName(Tag);
  for i := 0 to Pred(Collection.length) do
  begin
    E := Collection.item(i, EmptyParam) as IHTMLElement;

    for j := 0 to Attributes.Count-1 do
    begin
      FAttributeName:=LowerCase(List(Attributes,j,0,','));
      FAttributeValue:=LowerCase(List(Attributes,j,1,','));

      if not VarIsNull(E.getAttribute(FAttributeName,0)) then
      begin
        if (E.getAttribute(FAttributeName,0)=FAttributeValue) then
        Inc(Count,1);
      end;

      if Count = Attributes.Count then
      Exit(E);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Attributes:TStringList;
begin
    Attributes:=TStringList.Create;
    Attributes.Add('id,something');
    Attributes.Add('class,something');
    FindElement('sometag',Attributes);
    Attributes.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
E := Collection.item(i, EmptyParam) as IHTMLElement;
// you should clear the value of matched attributes counter for each element
Count := 0;
for j := 0 to Attributes.Count-1 do
  begin
```

**P.S.** 
A little optimization:

```
if not VarIsNull(E.getAttribute(FAttributeName,0)) then
begin
  if (E.getAttribute(FAttributeName,0)=FAttributeValue) then
  Inc(Count,1);
end else 
  // if any of attributes of element is not found, you can skip to next element.
  break;
```

Comment: Problem this code will not get attribute for some elements.. such as `<time class=entry-data>`

Comment: Some attributes, like `class`, have their own separate property, so it is possible that `getAttribute()` is filtering them out.

Comment: Another optimization is to call `getAttribute()` only once and cache its result to a local variable, then you can use that as many times as you want.